# left join queryBuilder symfony3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join, query-builder

I'm using Doctrine's QueryBuilder to build a query, and I want to get the count of each value in the table alongside with the value.

this is the SQL query

```
SELECT choice.choice ,count(*) 
FROM answer 
LEFT JOIN choice ON answer.answer_id_id = choice.id 
WHERE choice.survey_id=1  
GROUP BY choice ;
```

It returns a table with two columns, the value(choice) and the count

This is the query builder:

```
class AnswerRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getSurveyAnswers($idSurvey)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder("a");
        $query
            ->select('COUNT(a.answerId),e.choice')
            ->leftJoin("a.answerId",'e')->addSelect('e.choice')
            ->where('e.Survey = :surv')
            ->setParameter('surv',$idSurvey);

        $kk = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
        dump($kk);
        die();
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this it returns an array which contains the number of rows and the first value.

Comment: Could you post your entity model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `groupby()` in your query builder, therefore SQL database returns all rows agregated into a single one.

Try  to add grouping to your query builder:

```
->groupby('e.choice')
```